# Is there an analog of "regular" for infinite strings?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Consider the sequence $s_1 = (1, 0, 1, 0,\dots)$.  It seems "regular" in a way that, e.g. $s_2 = (1, 2, 3, 4,\dots)$ is not.

I'm not sure how to formalize this intuition though. One thing which jumps out at me is that $L =\{(0 1)^n\}$ is a regular language, and $s_1$ is in some sense the limit of the strings in this language.

Is there a terminology for considering these infinite strings? Do we have something analogous to the pumping lemma, whereby we can state that any such "infinite regular" string is of the form $x y^ {\infty}z$ with $x$, $y$, $z$ finite?

Comment: Perhaps *periodic* or *eventually periodic*.

Comment: **Pumping**: Your statement about infinite strings is hardly an analogue of the [Pumping Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages), which says that sufficiently long words in a regular language contain a substring which may be repeated to yield another word. It does not say that all words have that form!

Comment: **Terminology**: You talk about a _string_ being regular, whereas the term _regular_ is normally applied to languages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Probably the most specific term to describe your first string, $010101\dots$ is *periodic*. A string $x_1x_2\dots$ (finite or infinite) is periodic if there is some $t$ such that, for all $i$, $x_i=x_{i+t}$. In the case of this example, we can take $t=2$. A slightly weaker notion is that a string is *eventually periodic* if there are $n$ and $t$ such that $x_i=x_{i+t}$ for all $i\geq n$.

More generally, though, there is a direct analogue of the regular languages, which is the [$\omega$-regular languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega-regular_language). These are recognized by natural generalizations of finite automata. The state set is still finite but the acceptance criterion must be modified to deal with infinite words – in particular, we can't just say "Accept if the automaton finishes in an accepting state" because the automaton never finishes processing its infinite input.

The simplest class of automata for infinite words are [Büchi automata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%BCchi_automaton). They are defined exactly like the finite automata you're used to, and they accept their input if at least one accepting state is visited infinitely often during the automaton's run. One difference from ordinary finite automata is that it turns out that nondeterministic Büchi automata are more powerful than deterministic ones, and the $\omega$-regular languages are the ones accepted by nondeterministic Büchi automata.  Other [sensible acceptance criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A9-automaton) lead to other automaton models which accept the same class of langauges.

Note that it doesn't quite make sense to write $xy^\omega z$, since you can't have anything *after* an infinite sequence of $y$s. At least, you can't if the positions in your string are indexed by the natural numbers. If they're indexed by larger ordinals this can make sense.

I can't actually remember if there's an analogue of the pumping lemma for $\omega$-regular languages. This is slightly embarrassing, though it is most of a decade since I taught a graduate class on this stuff.

Comment: Nice. Perhaps add explicitly that $\omega$-regular languages are finite unions of languages $AB^\omega$, where $A,B$ regular. Don't know about pumping, but sometimes it is useful to observe that each $\omega$-regular language must contain an eventually periodic string.

Comment: I've always hated the standard presentation of the pumping lemma for being so damn obtuse. When you get right down to it, all it really says is that since there's a finite set of states, any string with more symbols than there are states must visit some state twice during a run of the automaton. The symbols participating in this loop are the ones you can "pump". Cast in this light, it is clear that there is an analog when we transition to infinite strings but retain finite states; so the question is not "is there a pumping lemma?" but "how much more complicated is the pumping lemma?".

Comment: @DanielWagner: Wow, yeah... the standard presentation is indeed pretty damn obtuse and yours makes it vividly clear. Thank you for that explanation!

Comment: @DanielWagner: the pumping lemma certainly is confusing, but the advantage of the standard presentation is that it does not refer to the mechanics of automata, regular expressions, or any other particular way of defining regular languages. It only talks about strings!

Comment: @Max A dubious advantage indeed!

Comment: @DanielWagner One would hope that the pumping lemma would be given _with proof_, and the proof conveys exactly the intuition you give in your proof. Also, the more complicated acceptance criteria of $\omega$-automata make it unclear whether there is any meaningful pumping lemma, both in the sense of a lemma that's possible to use in practice but also in terms of whether pumping captures a large enough fragment of non-$\omega$-regularity to be worthwhile

Comment: @DanielWagner: it's very possibly true that it's easier to remember the proof of the pumping lemma than the statement, and so it might be easier to just re-prove a specialised version of it each time than to use the general statement. This probably says something about how we prefer to teach theorems than techniques even when the latter would be better. But I would love to see a better statement of the pumping lemma that is just as useful (if it requires the construction of an NFA, one can just use the full Myhill-Nerode Theorem, and your lemma adds nothing). I love new pumping lemmas :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a basic result in Type Two Effectivity, which I think answers your question from a computable point of view. In the following, our languages consist only of infinite strings. We denote the set of infinite strings $\Sigma^\omega$.

> Theorem: If a realizable automaton terminates on every infinite string, then the language of the automaton is equal to $S\Sigma^\omega$ where $S$ is a finite set of finite strings.

The [proof](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2007/10/how-can-it-possibly-be-that-we-can.html) is by Konig's lemma.

The conclusion is that a language over infinite strings is either "simple" in some sense (which is [an interesting fact](http://math.andrej.com/2007/09/28/seemingly-impossible-functional-programs/)) or undecidable. Any non-trivial notion of language over infinite strings is undecidable.

---

You can presumably study less simple languages if you allow membership to be *semidecidable* rather than decidable. This can still be considered "computer science" and not just infinitary mathematics (it's to do with search problems instead of decision problems; semidecidability is in a sense sufficient for doing a search).